# How to communicate with external system

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to write a logic (js script) to communicate with external system. As far as understand, logic will be executed on all endorsing peer.
In this case, how can I avoid duplicate operation to external system ? For example, how to increment a value in external database ? If I write a logic to increment the value in js, I think the value will be incremented by all endorsing peer.
I'll appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, currently the only way you can interact with external systems is using the experimental `post` API. This allows your Transaction Processor function to HTTP POST data to an external system and then to process the response.

Documentation here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/call-out.html

You are correct in stating that if you have 4 peers, then the chain code container for each peer will run your logic, so you'd expect to see 4 calls to your HTTP service. This is required because each peer node is independent and Fabric must achieve consensus across the peers.

The external functions should therefore (ideally) be side-effect free "pure" functions (idempotent), meaning that for a given set of input parameters you always get the same set of output results.

Clearly a function that returns an incrementing integer doesn't fit this description! You probably need to rethink how you are structuring your problem to make it compatible with a decentralised blockchain-based approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. That's very valuable for me so that I understand my design doesn't fit composer's architecture. I'll rethink the structure of business network.

Comment: I also realized that RWset sent to Ordering Service can become invalid depending on version of Ledger. In this case, I need to undo the "side effect", but there is no way to do that.

Comment: Transactions are automatically rolled back if there is an MVCC version failure (optimistic commit failure).